# jquery ajax call on button click validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm submitting a form on a btn click using jquery ajax call. I'm doing form validation and if input is not valid then need to stop the ajax call. I've tried the following code but form submits every time even when the conditions fail

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnSubmit').click(function (evt) {
            if (ValidateUserInput()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("SearchResults", "Request")',
                    data: { searchTerm: $("#searchTerm").val(), searchFilter: $("#searchFilter").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#Results').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }

        });

    });

    function ValidateUserInput() {

        if ($('#searchFilter').val() == 'RequestId' && $('#searchTerm').val() != parseInt($('#searchTerm').val())) {
            $('#HiddenInvalidInputContainer').show(); 
            return false;

        }
        else {
            alert('testing');
            $('#HiddenInvalidInputContainer').hide(); 
            return true;
        }

    }

</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to prevent default behaviour of submit button, otherwise the FORM is submited... Now use the search box here, there is many examples on how to prevent FORM submiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always get the else clause, as this is always false for a number

```
$('#searchTerm').val() != parseInt($('#searchTerm').val()
```

`"1" != parseInt("1")` is false, `"1" !== parseInt("1")` is true

if you are trying to test for not-a-number, then you could use `isNaN()`